# Как сократить или оптимизировать код?

Tags: python, pygame

```
import random
import pygame
import time


def start_point_generate(n, m):
    """Функция выбора точки начала лабиринта"""
    if random.choice([True, False]):
        if random.choice([True, False]):
            start = (0, random.randint(0, m - 1))
        else:
            start = (n - 1, random.randint(0, m - 1))
    else:
        if random.choice([True, False]):
            start = (random.randint(0, n - 1), 0)
        else:
            start = (random.randint(0, n - 1), m - 1)
    return start


def finish_point_generate(start, n, m):
    """Выбор точки конца лабиринта"""
    return n - 1 - start[0], m - 1 - start[1]


def transition_choice(x, y, rm):
    """Функция выбора дальнейшего пути в генерации лабиринта"""
    choice_list = []
    if x > 0:
        if not rm[x - 1][y]:
            choice_list.append((x - 1, y))
    if x < len(rm) - 1:
        if not rm[x + 1][y]:
            choice_list.append((x + 1, y))
    if y > 0:
        if not rm[x][y - 1]:
            choice_list.append((x, y - 1))
    if y < len(rm[0]) - 1:
        if not rm[x][y + 1]:
            choice_list.append((x, y + 1))
    if choice_list:
        nx, ny = random.choice(choice_list)
        if x == nx:
            if ny > y:
                tx, ty = x * 2, ny * 2 - 1
            else:
                tx, ty = x * 2, ny * 2 + 1
        else:
            if nx > x:
                tx, ty = nx * 2 - 1, y * 2
            else:
                tx, ty = nx * 2 + 1, y * 2
        return nx, ny, tx, ty
    else:
        return -1, -1, -1, -1


def create_labyrinth(n=5, m=5):
    """Генерация лабиринта"""
    reach_matrix = []
    for i in range(n):  # создаём матрицу достижимости ячеек
        reach_matrix.append([])
        for j in range(m):
            reach_matrix[i].append(False)
    transition_matrix = []
    for i in range(n * 2 - 1):  # заполнение матрицы переходов
        transition_matrix.append([])
        for j in range(m * 2 - 1):
            if i % 2 == 0 and j % 2 == 0:
                transition_matrix[i].append(True)
            else:
                transition_matrix[i].append(False)
    start = start_point_generate(n, m)
    finish = finish_point_generate(start, n, m)
    list_transition = [start]
    x, y = start
    reach_matrix[x][y] = True
    x, y, tx, ty = transition_choice(x, y, reach_matrix)
    for i in range(1, m * n):
        while not (x >= 0 and y >= 0):
            x, y = list_transition[-1]
            list_transition.pop()
            x, y, tx, ty = transition_choice(x, y, reach_matrix)
        reach_matrix[x][y] = True
        list_transition.append((x, y))
        transition_matrix[tx][ty] = True
        x, y, tx, ty = transition_choice(x, y, reach_matrix)
    return transition_matrix, start, finish  # возвращаем матрицу проходов и начальную точку


def draw_labyrinth(matrix, start, finish, width_line=20, width_walls=5, color_way=(255, 255, 255),
                   color_wall=(0, 0, 0),
                   border=5, color_start=(0, 255, 0), color_finish=(255, 0, 0)):
    """Рисование лабиринта"""
    width = (len(matrix) // 2 + 1) * width_line + (len(matrix) // 2) * width_walls + border * 2
    height = (len(matrix[0]) // 2 + 1) * width_line + (len(matrix[0]) // 2) * width_walls + border * 2
    for i in range(width):
        for j in range(height):
            if i < border or width - i <= border or j < border or height - j <= border:  # отображение границ лабиринта
                pygame.draw.line(window, color_wall, [i, j], [i, j], 1)
            else:
                if (i - border) % (width_line + width_walls) <= width_line:
                    x = (i - border) // (width_line + width_walls) * 2
                else:
                    x = (i - border) // (width_line + width_walls) * 2 + 1
                if (j - border) % (width_line + width_walls) <= width_line:
                    y = (j - border) // (width_line + width_walls) * 2
                else:
                    y = (j - border) // (width_line + width_walls) * 2 + 1
                if matrix[x][y]:
                    pygame.draw.line(window, color_way, [i, j], [i, j], 1)
                else:
                    pygame.draw.line(window, color_wall, [i, j], [i, j], 1)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, color_start, (
        border + start[0] * (width_line + width_walls), border + start[1] * (width_line + width_walls), width_line,
        width_line))
    pygame.draw.rect(window, color_finish, (
        border + finish[0] * (width_line + width_walls), border + finish[1] * (width_line + width_walls), width_line,
        width_line))


def delete_player():
    """Функция удаления игрока при движении и оставления следов"""
    if (player[0], player[1]) == start:
        pygame.draw.circle(window, color_start, (border + player[0] * (width_line + width_walls) + width_line // 2,
                                                 border + player[1] * (width_line + width_walls) + width_line // 2),
                           width_line // 2 - 3)
    else:
        pygame.draw.circle(window, color_way, (border + player[0] * (width_line + width_walls) + width_line // 2,
                                               border + player[1] * (width_line + width_walls) + width_line // 2),
                           width_line // 2 - 3)
    if trace:
        pygame.draw.circle(window, color_trace, (border + player[0] * (width_line + width_walls) + width_line // 2,
                                                 border + player[1] * (width_line + width_walls) + width_line // 2),
                           width_line // 3 - 3)


def draw_player():
    """Отрисовка игрока на экране"""
    pygame.draw.circle(window, color_player, (border + player[0] * (width_line + width_walls) + width_line // 2,
                                              border + player[1] * (width_line + width_walls) + width_line // 2),
                       width_line // 2 - 3)


def tick():
    """Cекудномер"""
    global start_time, t
    t = time.time() - start_time


def click_RIGHT(m):
    """Движение вправо"""
    global player
    if len(m) > player[0] * 2 + 2:
        if m[player[0] * 2 + 1][player[1] * 2]:
            player[0] += 1


def click_LEFT(m):
    """Движение влево"""
    global player
    if -1 < player[0] * 2 - 2:
        if m[player[0] * 2 - 1][player[1] * 2]:
            player[0] -= 1


def click_DOWN(m):
    """Движение вниз"""
    global player
    if len(m[0]) > player[1] * 2 + 2:
        if m[player[0] * 2][player[1] * 2 + 1]:
            player[1] += 1


def click_UP(m):
    """Движение вверх"""
    global player
    if -1 < player[1] * 2 - 2:
        if m[player[0] * 2][player[1] * 2 - 1]:
            player[1] -= 1


def setting_trace():
    """Изменение флага оставления следов"""
    global trace
    if trace:
        trace = False
    else:
        trace = True


def new_game():
    global record_time, start_time, player, matrix, start, finish, matrix_base
    window.fill((0, 0, 0))
    start_time = time.time()
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (0, 0, 0), (0, height_window - 70, width_window, 70))
    matrix, start, finish = create_labyrinth(width, height)
    k = 0
    while matrix in matrix_base or start[0] == finish[0] or start[1] == finish[1]:
        matrix, start, finish = create_labyrinth(width, height)
        k += 1
        if k > 20:
            print('Не найдено лабиринтов без повторения')
            break
    matrix_base.append(matrix)
    player = list(start)
    draw_labyrinth(matrix, start, finish, width_line, width_walls, color_way,
                   color_wall,
                   border, color_start, color_finish)
    draw_player()


"""Системные переменные"""
border = 5
width_line = 40
width_walls = 5
color_way = (255, 255, 255)
color_wall = (0, 0, 0)
color_player = (0, 0, 255)
color_start = (0, 255, 0)
color_finish = (255, 0, 0)
trace = False
color_trace = color_player
width = 10
height = 10
width_window = ((width * 2 - 1) // 2 + 1) * width_line + ((width * 2 - 1) // 2) * width_walls + border * 2
height_window = ((height * 2 - 1) // 2 + 1) * width_line + ((height * 2 - 1) // 2) * width_walls + border * 2
info = True
score = 0
t = 0
record_time = 9999
if width < 10:
    info = False
if info:
    height_window += 70
matrix_base = []

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((width_window, height_window))
pygame.display.set_caption("Лабиринт")

font = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)
flag_game = True
matrix, start, finish = create_labyrinth(width, height)
k = 0
while matrix in matrix_base or start[0] == finish[0] or start[1] == finish[1]:
    k += 1
    if k > 20:
        print('Не найдено лабиринтов без повторения')
        break
    matrix, start, finish = create_labyrinth(width, height)
matrix_base.append(matrix)
player = list(start)
start_time = time.time()
draw_labyrinth(matrix, start, finish, width_line, width_walls, color_way,
               color_wall,
               border, color_start, color_finish)
draw_player()

while flag_game:  # основной игровой цикл
    delete_player()
    if tuple(player) == finish:
        window.fill((0, 0, 0))
        score += 1
        if t < record_time:
            record_time = t
        start_time = time.time()
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (0, 0, 0), (0, height_window - 70, width_window, 70))
        matrix, start, finish = create_labyrinth(width, height)
        k = 0
        while matrix in matrix_base or start[0] == finish[0] or start[1] == finish[1]:
            matrix, start, finish = create_labyrinth(width, height)
            k += 1
            if k > 20:
                print('Не найдено лабиринтов без повторения')
                break
        matrix_base.append(matrix)
        player = list(start)
        draw_labyrinth(matrix, start, finish, width_line, width_walls, color_way,
                       color_wall,
                       border, color_start, color_finish)
        draw_player()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            flag_game = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                click_RIGHT(matrix)
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                click_LEFT(matrix)
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_w:
                click_UP(matrix)
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                click_DOWN(matrix)
            if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                pass
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                setting_trace()
            if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                new_game()
            if event.key == pygame.K_e:
                player[0] = start[0]
                player[1] = start[1]
    if info and width >= 10:
        text1 = font.render("Пройдено лабиринтов: " + str(score), True, (255, 255, 255))
        window.blit(text1, [5, height_window - 65])
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (0, 0, 0), (5, height_window - 40, width_window, 20))
        text2 = font.render("Время: " + str(int(t)), True, (255, 255, 255))
        window.blit(text2, [5, height_window - 40])
        if record_time == 9999:
            text3 = font.render("Рекордное время: " + str(0), True, (255, 255, 255))
            window.blit(text3, [5, height_window - 20])
        else:
            text3 = font.render("Рекордное время: " + str(int(record_time)), True, (255, 255, 255))
            window.blit(text3, [5, height_window - 20])
    draw_player()
    tick()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Вынести ваши "системные переменные" в отдельный файл, `config.py`, к примеру. Обернуть все в классы

Comment: `while flag_game` придумать бы, как избавиться от этого цикла... оно постоянно бежит и жрет CPU, когда картинку реально нужно обновлять только после нажатия кнопок. `if random.choice([True, False]):` → `if random.random() < 0.5:`